# Filter pandas dataframe rows where a specific row with column A and value X has column B with value Y greater than a parameter Z

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I wonder if there's a simpler way to filter a pandas DataFrame rows where a specific row with column A and value X has column B with value Y greater than a parameter Z.

---

For example:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 72154 | X1 | 0.998429 |
| 72155 | X2 | 0.584253 |
| 72156 | X3 | 0.797648 |
| 72157 | X2 | 0.981707 |
| 72158 | X1 | 0.698844 |
| 72159 | X3 | 0.987943 |
| 72160 | X1 | 0.797648 |
| 72161 | X3 | 0.984621 |
| 72162 | X2 | 0.221968 |

I've managed to get it done with this code:

```
import pandas as pd

Z = 0.8
mask1 = (df.A.isin(['X1', 'X2']))
mask2 = (df.B > Z)
mask3 = (df.A == 'X3')
sub_df_x1_x2 = df[mask1 & mask2]
sub_df_x3  = df[mask3]
final_df = pd.concat([sub_df_x1_x2, sub_df_x3])
```

But I don't believe this is the cleanest or best way to do it.
Do you guys have any idea? I was thinking about something like this, but I was not able to get it to work.

```
mask1 = (df.A.isin(['X1', 'X2']) & df.B > Z)
# or
mask1 = (df.A.isin(['X1', 'X2'])[B] > Z)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could chain the two with `|`:

```
out = df[(df.A.isin(['X1', 'X2']) & (df.B > Z)) | (df.A == 'X3')]
```

or using the definitions you already have:

```
out = df[(mask1 & mask2) | mask3]
```

Output:

```
        A         B
72154  X1  0.998429
72156  X3  0.797648
72157  X2  0.981707
72159  X3  0.987943
72161  X3  0.984621
```

Comment: @Ricardo concatenation is making a union, so yeah